# build a spring login app which matches username and password from database

Tags: spring

i want to build a spring login app..in which password and usernames are saved in database and authentication will be done by matching those credentials.
i have done it without using database

```
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("loginform.html")
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(Map model) {
        LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
        model.put("loginForm", loginForm);
        return "loginform";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(@Valid LoginForm loginForm, BindingResult result,
            Map model) {
        String userName = "nayak";
        String password = "pass";
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "loginform";

        }




        loginForm = (LoginForm) model.get("loginForm");
        if (!loginForm.getUserName().equals(userName)
                || !loginForm.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            return "loginerror";
        }
        model.put("loginForm", loginForm);
        return "loginsuccess";
    }
}
```

now if i use database how to map this section

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(@Valid LoginForm loginForm, BindingResult result,
            Map model) {
        String userName = "nayak";
        String password = "pass";
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "loginform";

        }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are inventing your own and not use something like Spring Security which supports this out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring [JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html). To work with it just add `dataSource` and `JdbcTemplate` beans in your `applicationcontext.xml` and autowire the same.

**applicationcontext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">

   <!-- Initialization for data source -->
   <bean id="dataSource" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TEST"/>
      <property name="username" value="root"/>
      <property name="password" value="password"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

**LoginController.java:**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("loginform.html")
public class LoginController {

   @Autowire
   private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(Map model) {
        LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
        model.put("loginForm", loginForm);
        return "loginform";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(@Valid LoginForm loginForm, BindingResult result,
            Map model) {
     //   String userName = "nayak";
     //   String password = "pass";
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "loginform";

        }


        // Then query Database using jdbcTemplateObject
        String SQL = "select * from User where id = ?";
        User user = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(SQL, 
                    new Object[]{id}, new RowMapper<User>(){
        @Override
        public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
                throws SQLException {
            User user = new User();
            user.setUserName(rs.getString("username"));
            user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
            return user;
        }});

        loginForm = (LoginForm) model.get("loginForm");
        if (!loginForm.getUserName().equals(user.getUserName())
                || !loginForm.getPassword().equals(user.getPassword())) {
            return "loginerror";
        }
        model.put("loginForm", loginForm);
        return "loginsuccess";
    }
}
```